# What is the verb for "to make something into a plugin"?

Tags: terminology, language-agnostic, jargon

What is the verb for "to make something into a plugin"?

Example use: "Developer can you make Module Foo into a plugin?". "Yes sir, I can `some verb` Module Foo".

Terms I have considered: pluginify, pluginize, make pluggable

Criteria for Acceptance: A single verb which means "to make something into a plugin" or "to create something as a plugin". *I am looking for a term which is already in use* as opposed to a new one.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: Thanks @gnat. I am trying to find a verb which already exists so I can search documentation. I am not trying to name a class nor come up with a new term.

Comment: Modularize is the closest word I can think of.  Or perhaps componentize.  That's what you do when you transform something into a plugin.

Comment: `pluggenate` (sometimes `plugginate`)

Comment: how about "ruin"? that's a good verb...

Comment: Empahsis on a term already in use which would make this factual as opposed to making up a new term which is very subjective.

Comment: How about not trying to turn everything into a verb and just form a proper sentence when you talk with people?

Answer (score 3):

I have never encountered any such word. Just say "We can turn Module Foo into a plugin" or "We can wrap Module Foo in a plugin".

If you're looking for documentation and examples on plugin systems you can start with [searching for "plugin design"](https://www.google.com/search?q=plugin%20design).

Answer (score 1):

I would say "extract," as in you pull the functionality of this module out of the main codebase and extract it into a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

'Make pluggable' is the shortest it can get without inventing new words. Judging by latest Visual Studio and Chrome versions an 'extension' is a more fashionable word these days. Since the hardest bit is supporting plug-ins rather than writing a plug-in, searching for 'extensible architecture' would make more sense. 'Packages' and 'package management' are another trending pair of concepts of the day.